# Infinite Loop on Cached collection in Multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, ehcache, hashset

My application is running on tomcat with Spring and Hibernate framework. It uses EHCache as a cache provider in service level. That means objects created by service classes are put into the cache. (Not hibernate Dao objects).

There are some collection objects (HashSet, ArrayList, HashMap) in these cached objects. Non of them are synchronized collections. All are not thread safe, but they are not modified by the application after they are put into the cache.

I found infinite loop in many occasions when I loop through this collection. Some of the loops are Iterator loops and some others are old for loops run base on int index.

I managed to overcome one infinite loop by replacing a HashSet with Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet()). But I don't understand the real problem of using normal HashSet as it's never being modified by the application. (Does EHCache modify them?)

Please explain to me if there are any concerns here using non-thread safe collections.

```
public class HotelDetails implements Serializable { /*Objects in the cache */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
.....

private Set<String> facilities = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

Following loop run infinitely and blow out the heap

```
if (hotelDetails.getFacilities() != null && hotelDetails.getFacilities().size() > 0) {
for (String fac : hotelDetails.getFacilities()) {
    TFacility f = of.createTFacility();
    f.setCode(fac);
    f.setValue(fac);
    facilities.getFacility().add(f);
}
}
```

once replace the HashSet, the problem solved

```
public class HotelDetails implements Serializable { /*Objects in the cache */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
.....

private Set<String> facilities = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
}
```

And this is another one

```
private int getRatesStartIndex(GsRoomRate gsRoomRate, List<GsRate> gsRates, Date travelStart) {
    Integer startIndex = gsRoomRate.getGsRateIndexes().get(travelStart);
    if (startIndex==null) {
        for (startIndex=0; startIndex<gsRates.size(); startIndex++) {
            GsRate gsRate = gsRates.get(startIndex);
            if (travelStart.between(gsRate.getStartDate(), gsRate.getEndDate())) {
                gsRoomRate.getGsRateIndexes().put(travelStart, startIndex);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (startIndex>=gsRates.size()) startIndex = 0;
    }

    return startIndex;
}


public class GsRoomRate implements Serializable { /*Objects in the cache */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<GsRate> gsRates = new ArrayList<GsRate>();
    private Map<Date, Integer> gsRateIndexes = new HashMap<Date, Integer>();
}

public class GsRate implements Serializable { /*Objects in the cache */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private RBADate startDate;
    private RBADate endDate;
}
```

Comment: After changing to synchronized sets, do your calls ever return?  How do you know that you are getting into an infinite loop?  You seemed to indicate that you think you are in an inifnite loop  because you are running out of heap space...?

Answer (score 1):

EHCache doesn't modify your objects in any way. There is one exception: If you have a disk-based cache (i.e. a cache that can overflow to disk), then EHCache will serialize your objects, write them to disk and load them again if they are needed.

So if there is a problem serializing your objects **and** you have configured EHCache to spill over, this could cause problems but it doesn't feel like your issue.

My guess is that several objects with the same ID are put into the cache or that objects are added to the cache before they are completely initialized.

How to debug this?

1. Use `Collections.unmodifiable*()` to get errors if someone tries to modify a collection after having added it to the cache.
2. Save the `hashCode()` of the collection and validate it. The `hashCode()` changes if a) the collection changes or b) if the `hashCode()` of an object in the collection changes.

Especially the latter is a nice source of unforeseen problems: People use non-final fields in hashCode(), add objects to sets/maps and odd things happen.

Comment: Thanks Aaron... After some more investigation, found out that HashMap cause the problem. It's internal loop on get() method runs infinitely. Can find lot of information on this issue. But not direct answers. Is it safe to use HashMap in multi threaded application if the HashMap is not going to be modifyed?

Comment: Yes, all Java structures are safe as long as the aren't modified. Your description sounds like thread A adds data while thread B gets data from the map. That can cause all kinds of problems. Try ConcurrentHashMap to see if that fixes the problem. Or `Collections.unmodifiable*()` as per my answer above.